# sql - request.form and INSERT INTO format

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use request.form to get data from the user and save that to data base by INSERT INTO ... VALUES

my code was

```
    statement = "INSERT INTO Course(cId, cName) VALUES (%s, %s)" , (cId,cName)
    result = conn.execute(statement);
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

The code compiles but when it is running on web, it gives me a value error. Error message is

```
ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode
```

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my format in the first line. but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a tuple with two elements, not a single string. You need to pass in the parameters as a *separate argument*:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO Course(cId, cName) VALUES (%s, %s)"
params = (cId,cName)
result = conn.execute(statement, params)
```

Just because a call uses commas, does not mean you can transfer that comma to a tuple and have it mean the same thing.

You *can* unpack the tuple using `conn.execute(*statement)` syntax, but that's overkill here as you don't have a variable number of arguments to begin with.